# Access fails to group data!

Tags: ms-access

In this example Query,

```
SELECT [Account Transactions].ID, [Account Transactions].Transaction_Amount, *
FROM [Account Transactions]
GROUP BY [Account Transactions].ID, [Account Transactions].Transaction_Amount;
```

This Idea is to Group Account Transaction.ID's and capture the Sum of tracaction_amount for all transaction of the same ID.

The code was generated by Access 2016 and when executed I get:

> Can not group on Fields with '*'

The interesting thing is that I can generate a report with the very same grouping and it works perfectly.

Comment: If your idea is "_to Group Account Transaction.ID's and capture the Sum of tracaction_amount_" then your query is not doing that at all.

Comment: It's possible that part of the issue is the fact that, by including `*`, you've technically got *two* `ID` and *two* `Transaction_Amount` columns; the named ones, and the ones that are included as part of the `*` columns.

Answer (score 0):

The grouping may be the same, but you have an asterisk (shortcut for select all field, but the sequence is unkown what prevents grouping and aggregation) at the end of your selected fields that causes the error.

If you want to get the sum of `Transaction_Amount` per `ID` you just group by `ID` not by `Transaction_Amount`

```sql
SELECT
    Sum([Account Transactions].Transaction_Amount) As SumAmount
  , [Account Transactions].ID
FROM
    [Account Transactions]
GROUP BY
    [Account Transactions].ID
```

Comment: Yes, I have discovered the proper answer to this issue and it's quite simple.

Comment: Yes, I have discovered the proper answer to this issue and it's quite simple.  The SQL created contains a ',*' view the SQL statement and remove those characters, it will now work.  This is derived from the Query Property Sheet "Display All Fields' the others are Yes or No. if you select Yes, this tells access to show all filed in the tables found in the Query.  Thus if you are doing a grouping Access will attempt to Group ALL fields in the Query, which in most case it can't thus the error.  Cryptic as it is!

Answer (score 0):

This is touched on by [ComputerVersteher](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/219113/116653)'s answer, but to address it more explicitly:

Access told you exactly what the problem was. You can't use `GROUP BY` when you're using `*` in your `SELECT` list.

Note that `SELECT *` indicates to include every column in the table as of the time the statement is executed. In your case, you're actually including a second copy of the `ID` and the `Transaction_Amount` columns.

So, first - it's a bad idea to have multiple columns in your `SELECT` list with the same name/alias. If you really want to have `ID` and `Transaction_Amount` included multiple times, it would be best to provide an alias, so the columns in the result set all have unique names.

SQL statements with a `GROUP BY` have a restriction on what's in the `SELECT` list. Every column in the `SELECT` list should either by in the `GROUP BY` list, or should be in an aggregate function (like `SUM()`). By definition, none of the columns included by use of the `*` can be in aggregate functions. You can't use `*` in the `GROUP BY` clause. Since you *have* to specify the columns explicitly in `GROUP BY`, you would automatically have an invalid statement if any new column was added to the table. So, Access prevents you from using `SELECT *` and `GROUP BY` together.

Are you sure you didn't modify the code Access generated? I would be surprised if it would generate code it couldn't run.